# wxPython.Grid редактор ячейки не отрабатывает?

Tags: python, wxwidgets

```
def select_from_db(sql_string, grid_name):
    cur.execute(sql_string)
    z=0
    for x in cur:
        x1 = re.sub(r"[(,')]", "", str(x))
        self.grid_1.AppendRows(1)
        grid_name.SetCellValue(z, 0, str(x1))
        self.grid_1.SetReadOnly(z, 0, isReadOnly=True)
        z+=1
```

Есть такая функция, она принимает в виде строки sql запрос и grid табличку в которую будет выведен результат запроса.
В цикле проходит по данным из бд.
Приводит результат итерации в строку и режет спец символы по re выражению.
Добавляет при итерации поле в grid.
Закидывает в это поле результат.
Должно отключать возможность редактирования ячейки.
Увеличивает счетчик.

Но вот проблема. Редактор ячейки отключается для всех выведенных полей кроме первого в списке, отсчет идет с 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят. Косяк с редактором кода. Функция отрабатывает верно.

Comment: Дайте более развёрнутый ответ. Что не так с редактором?

Comment: pycharm каким то образом решил перепрыгивать первую итерацию цикла. Решилось очисткой временных файлов pycharm. и перезапуском по.